# compiled by a more recent version of Java Runtime(class file version 55.0),this version of Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm stuck with this problem for few days now. I have a Spring Boot application which I've created locally and I want to deploy it to Google Cloud App Engine. I'm using a Cloud Code plugin so that I can deploy from within Intellij. I've been trying to deploy from  gcloud CLI but I kept getting errors, so now I'm trying to do the same from within Intellij. This is the error that I'm getting:
[image]

I've set everything to java 11 in the project structure, and in the java compiler settings too, my local java version is also 11, what might be the problem?

Answer (score 7):

It's IDE Error.
In android Studio **File -> Settings -> Build, Execution & Development -> Build Tools -> Gradle and change Gradle JVM to 11**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I've set everything to java 11 in the project structure, and in the java compiler settings too, my local java version is also 11, what might be the problem?

Google is the problem. Specifically, evidently AppEngine itself, or possibly because you configured it that way, is limited to java8 which is end of lifed at this point (but still widely used). v52 is java8, v55 is java11.

Set your stuff to java8, recompile, try again.

Comment: but I have parts of the code that are only supported in java11, should I try to make changes to the code or move to another platform, eg heroku?

Comment: btw configuration was all default and I didn't change anything, my app.yaml only has runtime: java
env: flex

Comment: "java8 which is end of lifed at this point" - It is more complicated / nuanced than that.  See https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-se-support-roadmap.html for more details.  It depends on whether you are using Java for personal or commercial purposes.  And the "end of life" for commercial users is for the not-paid-for public releases.  (Commercial users can pay for supported Java 8 ....)

Comment: how??????????????????????????

Answer (score 0):

Set `runtime: java11` in your `app.yaml` file.